# XSLT: for each limit acts strange

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach

I have a for each with a limit of 3 items to display. 
The problem is that it if I limit it to 3...it doesn't begin with the first entry as it supposed to do. In stead it starts at the second one. 
I have my entries ranked from 001 to 020. And I sorted the for-each on this rank. So the first 4 would be displayed. 
So there should be something wrong with my for-each statements?

```
<xsl:for-each select="data/activity-feed/entry[recommended = 'Yes'][position() mod 4]">
   <xsl:sort select="activity-rank" data-type="number" order="ascending" />  
        <a href="{$root}/items">
                <p>  
                     <xsl:value-of select="activity-name"/>
                     <xsl:call-template name="description">
                </p>
        </a>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

My XML:

```
<data>
    <activity-feed>
        <entry id="65">
                <recommended>Yes</recommended>
                <activity-name handle="forra-dive">Forra Dive</activity-name>
                <activity-rank handle="001">001</activity-rank>
        </entry>
    </activity-feed>
</data>
```

Any idea how to make only the FIRST 4 display? 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that in the for-each select, `position()` is evaluated in the *unsorted* order of the entry. So you're getting the first 3 in the original (document) order instead of in the ranked order. If you show more of your input data we could tell for sure.

If that's the case, try:

```
<xsl:for-each select="data/activity-feed/entry[recommended = 'Yes']">
   <xsl:sort select="activity-rank" data-type="number" order="ascending" />  
   <xsl:if test="position() &lt; 4">
      <a href="{$root}/items">
         <p>  
            <xsl:value-of select="activity-name"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="description">
         </p>
      </a>
   </xsl:if>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

The fix is that we're testing for `position()` *inside* the sorted `for-each` loop, instead of "outside" the sort.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use modulus? If you use a static number, the loop limitation should succeed.

```
<xsl:for-each select="data/activity/entry[recommended='Yes'][position() < 4]>
    ...
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: I tried both '<' as '&lt;' which result in the same weird thing were the items start ranking from 002 and not from 001.

Comment: @Sandor, in that case something else is wrong. Are you sure the entry with ranking 001 has the recommended tag set to 'Yes'?